# weight training and Muscle imbalance (?)

Tags: joints

From last 6 months, I started with a knee issue and I find gradually more and more joints  like hips, shoulder, ankle becoming noisy (as in popping/ snapping /noises like rubbing of cartilage) and sometimes accompanied by pain and it is becoming scary.

I don't have ortho/PT specializing in sports medicine in my place and the rest haven't been of much help. One PT however did tell I have muscle imbalance, which I realize I do because of thoroughly unbalanced training and neglect in stretching.  But again he didn't mention which muscles and said I can do all kind of exercises I want, that I actually can't. I can't do exercises involves running, twisting and jumping and fast movements as in martial arts.

I was wondering if starting a balanced barbell training under a trainer and stretching sufficiently a good idea. I mean is that what people with joint issues do when they can't get medical help due to whatever reason.

It might look like paralysis by analysis but I started treatment with a PT with open mind and ended up worsening pain in my knees. This has made a skeptic out of me... I'm not sure if this kind (unspecific?) question is entertained is this forum.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a good idea for a physio to have a look at you to see if you truly have a muscle imbalance.  If you can afford to pay, see if you can find a sports physio. If not, go to the doctors, and explain that it has been suggested that you have a muscle imbalance and ask them to refer you to a physio.

If you have an imbalance the physio would be able to tell you the exercises to do to strengthen the muscles that need strengthening.